# Advanced SQLite3 SELECT query

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table much like the one in the example below that has a column that contains a list of items that are separated by commas. What I would like to know is if possible to use the features built into SQLite3; to build a SELECT query that will allow me to:

**A.**) Return the total number of times a specific color appears for all rows in the table.

**B.**) Sort the results so that they are listed first by how often they appear in the result-set and then alphabetically for any items that appear the same number of times.

I realize this may sound abit confusing so I will try to explain abit more in detail below, but first this is an example table that I am working with.

**Tablename**: demo_table

```
ID | Colors
---|-------------------------------------------
1  | red, green, blue, pink, yellow
2  | blue, purple, white, red
3  | green, black, orange, brown
4  | silver, white, blue
5  | brown, green, blue, black, red, purple, orange
```

**Result-Set:**

red(3), green(3), blue(4), pink(1), yellow(1), purple(2), white(2), black(2), orange(2), brown(2), silver(1)

**Result I would like to obtain after running the query**: blue, green, red, black

**Explanation:**

If it is not obvious from the result itself what I would like to do is return the first 4 items from the result-set which are sorted first by how often they appear in the result-set and since `Blue` was listed 4 times it would come first. `Green` was next because it was listed 3 times, `Red` comes next because it was listed 3 times, but since Red comes after Green in the alphabet, it comes after Green in the reult, and finally the last result is `Black` because even though there are other items that appear the same amount of times in the reult-set, it would be listed first in the alphabet and therefore it becomes the last item in the list since we are only looking for the frist 4 results.

What I am trying to create with all of this is a sort of "top 5" list from the items in the table column. In the end, I would like to give the end user the option to choose how the list is displayed, but I would first like to get the basics sorted out so I know if it's even possible to create such a system using SQLite3 alone.

Finally, if it is possible, what would such a query look like?

Comment: I do not think there is a 'split' function or something like with sqlite, so I am afraid that can not be done easily. You should look for another approach, like not storing CSV values.

Comment: Normalize your schema! Split out the CSV colors into a different table with one color per row, then link it back to the original table with a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: The problem is I do not have access to the Database Schema or I would of redesigned it along time ago so I have no other choice but to do it outside of the database